# Javascript fetch value from textarea and fill in different input field dynaically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, autofill

I want to fetch value from a textarea dynamically while I write and fill the value in a different input field. So that the input autofill itself from the text I write in textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the `textarea` id is 'myTextArea', and the `input` id is 'myInput'.
Using an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [onKeyUp event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event)(or whichever event suits your needs), you could simply do:

`const myTextArea = document.getElementyById('myTextArea');`
`const myInput = document.getElementyById('myInput');`
`myTextArea.addEventListener('keyup', () => myInput.value = myTextArea.value);`